# linear computation on very big matrix

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix

We need to compute all the linear combination (binary numbers modulo 2) on matrix row

```
    [C1|C2|C3|C4|C5|C6|C7]
R1: [1 |0 | 0| 0| 0| 0|1 ]
R2: [1 |0 | 0| 0| 0| 0|1 ]
R3: [1 |0 | 0| 0| 0| 0|1 ]
R4: [1 |0 | 0| 0| 0| 0|1 ]
```

1) R1, R2, R3, R4

2) R1+R2, R1+R3, R1+R4,
   R2+R3, R2+R4,
   R3+R4

3) R1+R2+R3, R1+R2+R4,
   R1+R3+R4

4) R1+R2+R3+R4

i) ...

I used a binomial tree but it is really slow because the matrix is huge (approx ~50000*50000)

```
bool Util::binomialTree(int start, int end, int depth, 
        int *tab_index, vector<YNumber*> resultatY,  int size_factor, mpz_t n){
    int i;
    // tab_index contains all the index of the 
    // matrix and depth contains the index numbers in tab_index
    // computation here
    for (i = start + 1; i < end; i++){
            if (binomialTree (i, end, depth + 1,tab_index,
                        resultatY, size_factor, n)){
                return true;
            }
     }
    return false;
}
```

Can you suggest an efficient algorithm?

Comment: Are you looking for the number of linear combinations of rows in a binary matrix (which is 2^NumberOfRows) or a listing of all of the linear combinations (which could be done as simply as going through a very large NumberOfRows-bit number and printing out which digits are set to one)?

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking of a prefix tree, in which characters are coordinates in the matrix. when you add to the tree add the value of the following coordinate to the value of the father node. this way you would only have to count (R1+R2+R3) once for (R1+R2+R3+R4) and (R1+R2+R3+R4+R5).

I hope this is understandable...

Care to explain why you chose a binomial tree?